# If $\|x_n-u_n\|\to 0$ and $x_{n_{i}}\rightharpoonup w,$ then $u_{n_{i}} \rightharpoonup w.$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Assuming that $\{u_n\}$ and $\{x_n\}$ are bounded sequences in a Hilbert space, $H$. Also, if $\|x_n-u_n\|\to 0$ and $x_{n_{i}}\rightharpoonup w,$ how does $u_{n_{i}} \rightharpoonup w?$

**My trial**
By Eberlein-Smul'yan Theorem, there exists a subsequence $\{u_{n_{k}}\}$ of $\{u_n\}$ such that $u_{n_{i}} \rightharpoonup u^*\in H$.

**Question:** How do I show that $u^*=w$ or from $\|x_{n_{i}}-u_{n_{i}}\|\to 0,$ that $u_{n_{i}} \rightharpoonup w?$

Comment: I guess you mean $w=0$?

Comment: I was reviewing a paper. It was from there I found this. [Here is the paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042708001179/pdfft?md5=5df028d8d22b564ef75e46416f293c14&pid=1-s2.0-S0377042708001179-main.pdf).

Comment: @Severin Schraven: Oh, sorry! I have just fixed the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\Vert x_n - u_n \Vert \rightarrow 0$ and thus $x_n - u_n \rightharpoonup 0$ (strong convergence implies weak convergence, this follows directly from Cauchy-Schwarz) and therefore $x_{n_i} - u_{n_i} \rightharpoonup 0$. However, if also $x_{n_i} \rightharpoonup w$, then we obtain $u_{n_i} = (u_{n_i} - x_{n_i}) + x_{n_i} \rightharpoonup 0 + w =w$.

Comment: Already fixed it :)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome.